# What is a safe state machine?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, terminology, quartus

When I implement a "safe" state machine in Quartus, what is the difference between a normal/unsafe state machine?

Edit: And is this the same as:

```
case state is  

...  

    when others =>
    nextState <= idle;

end case;
```

if you don't take into account that the synthesizer ignores this "when other"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A safe state machine in Quartus is a state machine that if it reaches an illegal state (for any exceptional reason, such as glitch, metastability, etc.), it will reach the reset state after one clock cycle.

Comment: ...and presumably consumes more FPGA resources to realize the state machine design.